# Managing categorical variables

Tags: stata

If a variable is encoded as string and not as numeric, does Stata recognize the categories automatically and treat the variable as categorical without the `i.` prefix?

What about variables defined as numeric with binary values (e.g. 0, 1)? Does Stata treat them as categorical automatically?

Answer (score 2):

For numeric variables you can use the `c.` prefix to treat it as continuous and the `i.` prefix to treat them as categorical. With string variables, convert them to encoded numeric variables first with `encode`, see `help encode`.

Comment: But is there a condition where categorical variables are automatically recognized ?

Comment: The concept of categorical variables is yours, not a Stata concept. Stata has the idea of factor variables and just a small experiment will show that they can't be string,  So, nothing here is automatic beyond string variables being string and numeric variables being numeric.